# Dropdown inside select in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have the following JSON object :

```
[{
    "Question": "Sample question One",
    "Options": [{
        "OptionId": 1,
        "Option": "Yes"
    }, {
        "OptionId": 2,
        "Option": "No"
    }]
}, {
    "Question": "Sample question Two",
    "Options": [{
        "OptionId": 1,
        "Option": "Yes"
    }, {
        "OptionId": 2,
        "Option": "No"
    }]
}, {
    "Question": "Sample question Three",
    "Options": [{
        "OptionId": 1,
        "Option": "Yes"
    }, {
        "OptionId": 2,
        "Option": "No",
    }, {
        "OptionId": 3,
        "Option": "May be",
    }]
}]
```

I am using a select with ng-options to iterate each question. Inside the select I am adding a dropdown with the options binded to it.

This is works properly.

Now I have to hide a div if the option selected for the second question is no and if the option selected is yes, i have to show the div.

I tried using `ng-show` and `ng-hide` based on a model property `"isDetailsVisible"`. I thought it would be easy to bind this to the second question's answer but I am unable to think of a way to do this.

Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: You should have rules for each option, and then based on each rule hide or show the question.

Comment: Can you share some of the form code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Ganesh for the detailed answer. I am expecting a little more simpler way.

I think I found an answer. I updated the JSON to make it easier, but this does not impact much.

```
        [{
            "Question": "Sample question One",
            "Options": ["Yes", "No"],
            "SelectedOption": "Yes"
        }, {
            "Question": "Sample question Two",
            "Options": ["Yes", "No"],
            "SelectedOption": "Yes"
        }, {
            "Question": "Sample question Three",
            "Options": ["Yes", "No"],
            "SelectedOption": "Yes"
        }]
```

on the html, I have the following :

```
<div class="col-md-12 nopadding" data-ng-repeat="Question in Questions">
<select ng-model="question.SelectedOption" ng-options="option for option in Question.Options"> </select></div>
```

and for the div which I have to show and hide, I am using ng-show.

```
 <div class="box-3" ng-show="Questions[1].SelectedOption === 'Yes'">
```

This works fine. But I feel the ng-show should have been mapped to a property or a method so that the logic resides in the controller and not in the html.

I would appreciate any comments on my above approach or any thoughts on how to have this logic moved to controller. Questions are not loaded initially. There is a button click on which the question loads and from that time I want the div to respond to the answer of the

second question. Till the question loads, the div is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you I think,

In this I have seperated the display as follows

**Custom directive questioninfo:** for displaying the information about the selected question. This also shows the options of the selected question, but before iterating, i use filter on the options to get only available options(with value 'Yes')

**Filter optionFilter:**  For filtering the options, I have applied the filter to select options with given value('Yes') in 'Option'

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.factory('dataService', function() {
  return {
    data: {
      "Questions": [{
        "Question": "Sample question One",
        "Options": [{
          "OptionId": 1,
          "Option": "Yes"
        }, {
          "OptionId": 2,
          "Option": "No"
        }]
      }, {
        "Question": "Sample question Two",
        "Options": [{
          "OptionId": 1,
          "Option": "No"
        }, {
          "OptionId": 2,
          "Option": "No"
        }]
      }]
    }

  };
});

// I am using this filter because options should not be many
app.filter('optionFilter', function() {
  return function(items, value) {
    if (!angular.isUndefined(items)) {
      var arrayToReturn = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].Option === value) {
          arrayToReturn.push(items[i]);
        }
      }

      return arrayToReturn;
    }
  };
});

app.directive('questioninfo', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      selectedQuestion:'=question'
    },

    controller: function($scope) {},
    template: '<h2>{{selectedQuestion.Question}}</h2>\
    <h3>Available Options</h3>\
     <div  ng-repeat="option in selectedQuestion.Options|optionFilter:\'Yes\'"> \
     <div ng-if="shouldShowOption(option)"><b>Option {{option.OptionId}}</b> {{option.Option}}</div>\
     </div>\
    \
     '

  };
})

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.data = dataService.data;
  $scope.Questions = dataService.data.Questions;
  $scope.selectedQuestion = dataService.data.Questions[1].Question;
});
```

HTML Code:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1>Select Question</h1>
    <select id="s1" ng-model="selectedQuestion" ng-options="item as item.Question for item in Questions">

    </select>
    <h3>The selected item just for reference:</h3>
    <pre>{{selectedQuestion | json}}</pre>
    <hr>
    <questioninfo question="selectedQuestion"></questioninfo>
  </body>

</html>
```

Check this link [Plunker]: http://plnkr.co/edit/LIVVofC8nyYtbYYVBBCb?p=preview